# How do I compress space characters with PHP regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex

```
$string = 'Hello    this is a bunch of numbers: 333 and letters and $pecial Characters@!*(';

$foo = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $string);

echo $foo;
```

The above returns:

```
Hello    this is a bunch of numbers 333 and letters and pecial Characters
```

I want to retain spaces but not if theres more than one. How can that be done?

It should look like:

```
Hello this is a bunch of numbers 333 and letters and pecial Characters
```

Comment: 'pecial' characters? Sure looks like `$` wasn't retained.

Comment: @Cyclone right, it should only retain letters, numbers and single spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$foo = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $string);
$foo = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$foo);
```

Comment: hmm, this returns: Hellothisisabunchofnumbers333andlettersandpecialCharacters all jumbled up. I wanted to retain spaces, just not more than one in a row.

Comment: yeah i realized that about 2s after I posted. See edit. Have to break it up into 2 regexes since you are replacing w/ 2 diff things.

Comment: You still need a `\s` inside the character class in the first replacement to avoid removing all whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

One regex will do it:

```
$foo = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]|(\s)\s+/', '$1', $string);
```

Comment: aah that's pretty slick, I didn't think to exploit captured groups

Comment: In php, if capture group 1 is undefined or null, is an empty string substituted? Or is $1 retained from the last match?

Comment: captured groups give an empty string if nothing was captured

Comment: @sin - `preg_replace()` converts NULL and/or undefined capture group values to an empty string. This can be very handy when you have a bunch of alternatives with only one matching at a time - I use it all the time (It works in Javascript too). I use this technique in my [LinkifyURL function](http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/linkifyurl/linkify.html "Look for the regex at the bottom of this test page")

Comment: @Crayon Violet - Ok, good to know. @ridgerunner - Massive regex there! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with PHP, but in Perl it's something like:

```
s/\s+/ /g
```

i.e. replace any sequence of one or more spaces with a single space.

So I imagine the PHP to compress spaces would be:

```
$foo = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/", " ", $string);
```

I don't think there should be any problems with running two preg_replace lines, especially if it makes the code clearer.

Comment: no, it does the same as your perl regex: replace 1 or more \s with a space. fyi preg_xxx functions use pcre regex (same as perl)

Comment: I was talking about the version you had up before your edit - but I edited my post to remove the last para since it was no longer true. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace globally (**edit** - tested):

`/(?<=\s)\s+|[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/`

with ""